# Firefox ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, firefox

I am using `wordpress` for my site, and its running file on all browsers expect `FireFox`.

In `firefox` my site load half without styles and `js` files, just html version with these errors in console.

```
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined www.domain.com:591

ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined www.domain.com:853

ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined www.domain.com:1262

ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined www.domain.com:1443

ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined www.domain.com:1665

ReferenceError: $ is not defined www.domain.com:1786

ReferenceError: $ is not defined www.domain.com:1795

ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

But I included `jQuery` in my head:

```
<script src="/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js"></script>
```

But still its not working in firefox.

Any idea why its behaving like this in firefox?

Comment: Is your code executing before the jquery scripts could have loaded? We can't help unless we can see the code that's generating the errors.

Comment: They all are loading after page loaded by using: `$(document).ready(function(){`

Comment: Are they declared before you load jQuery? IE are the script tags in the html doc before jquery?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be adding scripts to your head. Use wp_enqueue_script instead http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

In the example below I load jQuery and jQuery UI core. Loading jQuery UI core will load jQuery anyway but it's a good practise to specify it first.

There are more jQuery UI components so choose which you need from here:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Default_Scripts_Included_and_Registered_by_WordPress

```
function wpse_load_js() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-core' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_load_js' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow different way to enqueue JS in WordPress

step 1 - While enqueue script you have 2 kind of action-

a)'wp_enqueue_scripts' - this action will be use if you want to enqueue scripts on the front end.
example-

```
            /**
             * Proper way to enqueue scripts and styles
             */
            function theme_name_scripts() {
                wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name', get_stylesheet_uri() );
                wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/example.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
            }

            add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );
```

b) 'admin_enqueue_scripts' - this action will be use if you want to enqueue scripts on admin pages.

```
    function load_custom_wp_admin_style() {
            wp_register_style( 'custom_wp_admin_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/admin-style.css', false, '1.0.0' );
            wp_enqueue_style( 'custom_wp_admin_css' );
    }
    add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_custom_wp_admin_style' );
```

step 2- After use particular action your script will be enqueue.

To know more please check following link-
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts